# Cannot remove default buttons from autodesk-forge viewer panel (Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D)

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer, forge

I would like to remove **measure, text format and properties** buttons. See image.
I can only remove "toolbar-settingsTool" but not able remove above three buttons.

```
   onExtensionLoaded = (e) => {

    if (e.extensionId === 'Autodesk.DefaultTools.NavTools') {

        // Remove settings tools
        const settingsTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('settingsTools');
        settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-settingsTool');
        //settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-fullscreenTool');

        // Remove settings tools
        const navTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('navTools');
        navTools.removeControl('toolbar-propertiesTool');            

        // Remove model tools
        const modelTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('modelTools');
        modelTools.removeControl('toolbar-modelStructureTool');
    }
}
```

`viewer.addEventListener(
                Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT,
                this.onExtensionLoaded);`

Can you please help me? Thank you.

[viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2oyJ.png)

Here is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Some toolbars are initialized when loading the corresponding extension such as measurement ('Autodesk.Measure'). If you still need to use these functionalities in the workflow, yet only need to put the button to your own toolbars, or no button, you will need to check the corresponding extension if it supports removing  the button only. e.g. in 'Autodesk.Measure' extension, it has the method **measurementToolbarButton.removeFromParent**, by which, the default button will be removed, while the functionalities of measurement still exists. The code could be:

```
ext = NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure')
ext.measurementToolbarButton.removeFromParent()
```

When you need to switch to measure mode by your own button, call the method below:

```
 NOP_VIEWER.setActiveNavigationTool('measure')
```

If you do not need the functionalities  at all, just unload the extension. The default button will also be removed.

Comment: Is there any way to remove "Select Text" (T) icon?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Xiaodong Liang. That works. I was able to remove measure and properties icons using following code:

```
onExtensionLoaded = (e) => {

        // Remove "Settings" icon
        if (e.extensionId === 'Autodesk.DefaultTools.NavTools') {

            // Remove settings tools
            const settingsTools = viewer.toolbar.getControl('settingsTools');
            settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-settingsTool');
            //settingsTools.removeControl('toolbar-fullscreenTool');

        }
        // Remove measurement icon
        else if (e.extensionId === 'Autodesk.Measure') {

            var ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure');
            ext.measurementToolbarButton.removeFromParent();
        }
        // Remove "Text" icon
        else if (e.extensionId === 'Autodesk.Hyperlink') {

            var ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Hyperlink');
            ext.tool.removeFromParent();
        }
        // Remove properties icon
        else if (e.extensionId === 'Autodesk.PropertiesManager') {

            var ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.PropertiesManager');
            ext._toolbarButton.removeFromParent();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to remove "Select Text" (T) icon? Following code is not working:

```
var ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Hyperlink');
                ext.tool.removeFromParent();
```

Thank you.